# Creating onClick jquery tooltip on the basis of offset(). Everything works well apart when the user comes at the bottom, tool tip actually goes hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating onClick jquery tooltip on the basis of 'offset()'. Everything works well apart when the user comes at the bottom. Tool tip actually goes hide.

Its a obvious thing I have given the main container 'overflow:hidden'. But I would like to re-position the tool tip or may be this time not according to offset position.

Ultimately I don't want to hide it.

Any suggestion or help much appreciated. Apologies if I couldn't explain it in right manner.

Here is the code and fiddle URL:

```
$('#data-list > li').on('click', function(){        
        var $this = $(this), thisoffset = $this.offset().top;

        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
        $('.container-slide').animate({top:thisoffset-15}, 300).fadeIn();

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mufeedahmad/ndk44/12/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to check if the container-slide goes out of the wrapper box. You can add this line

```
if(thisoffset + $('.container-slide').height() > $(".wrapper").height())thisoffset = $(".wrapper").height() - $('.container-slide').height() + 15;
```

So the final code becomes

```
$('#data-list > li').on('click', function(){        
        var $this = $(this), thisoffset = $this.offset().top;

        if(thisoffset + $('.container-slide').height() > $(".wrapper").height())thisoffset = $(".wrapper").height() - $('.container-slide').height() + 15;

        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
        $('.container-slide').animate({top:thisoffset-15}, 300).fadeIn();

    });
```

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aZJuN/

Answer (score 0):

```
var divleftoffset = $(".wrapper").offset().left - $(document).scrollLeft();


var left = event.pageX; -$(document).scrollLeft();
menuWidth = $(".container-slide").width();
divWidth = $(".wrapper").width();
menuleft = menuWidth + left;
divleft = divleftoffset + divWidth;

var right;
if (menuleft > divleft) {
    left = left - menuWidth;
}

var divrightoffset = $(".wrapper").offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
var Top = event.pageY; -$(document).scrollTop();
menuHeight = $(".container-slide").height();
divHeight = $(".wrapper").height();
menuTop = menuHeight + Top;
divTop = divrightoffset + divHeight;

var right;
if (menuTop > divTop) {
    Top = Top - menuHeight;
}

$('.active').removeClass('active');
$this.addClass('active');
$('.container-slide').animate({ top: Top - 15 }, 300).fadeIn();
```

Comment: use $(this).offset().top instead of event.pageY SAME WITH event.pageX